# Can sunflares hit earth, and what are they?-Question from Maze Runner series

Tags: space

Well, Just want to know. What are sunflares, and can they hit earth now?

Comment: Are you asking about [the events from Maze Runner](http://mazerunner.wikia.com/wiki/Sun_Flares), or [solar flares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_flare) in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not Like You Would Think**

Solar Flares actually routinely hit earth every year, this is why we have the Aurora Borealis. The vast VAST majority of solar flares are not high energy enough to really do much except mess with sensitive communication equipment and create the northern lights. Solar Flares are intense bursts of high energy plasma on the surface of the sun, but due to gravity and magnetic properties they will always curve back inward to the surface of the sun. 
[image]

These do throw off intense bursts of high energy particles but our earths electromagnetic field typically captures them, this is why there are northern lights, and it creates some low level electromagnetic activity when it interacts with our magnetic field. Every few hundred to few thousand years there can be abnormally powerful solar activity. The last time this happened was in 1859 in an occurrence known as the Carrignton event. Thousands of fires were started when telegraph offices and transmitters shorted out, People could see the Aurora as far south as Baltimore, and the worlds early tele-communications network was basically destroyed. This was not really a big deal for them back then since it was a fledgling technology and there wasn't that much to replace or rebuild and it wasnt very complex to do so.

If a Carrington level event happened today the effects would be catastrophic. Virtually all power and communications transmission systems would fail, and the planet would be set back technologically almost 200 years literally overnight. Vast swathes of the population would starve to death as infrastructure broke down and emergency response is rendered nearly impossible due to a near complete inability to organise anything without communications. This is because the burst of high energy solar particles impacting our magnetosphere would cause a highly powerful electromagnetic pulse. EMP damages electronics by inducing a charge on metallic surfaces. This is only milli-volts per square foot of surface area exposed, normally pathetically tiny, but if you factor in the surface area of a 1000 mile long power line it adds up into a huge surge that blows the transformers. Additionally our electrical equipment is a lot more delicate and sensitive than a telegraph machine was in the 1800's. Only a tiny tiny surge between two micro-printed circuits is enough to irreparably damage a computerized device.

So, to summarize, the earth would not be bathed in radiation and fire, but pretty much most of our modern tech would fail and there would really be no way to organize a response to it. Society would be thrown into chaos and a lot of people would die before things evened out again. The thing is, these solar events are not only very very rare, but there is only a minuscule chance that it would even be directed at the earth if it even were to happen. It has a literally infinite number of vectors it could occur towards and only one that intersects with earth's orbit.